# Laravel eager loading problem. How do I fix the N+1 warning that I'm getting?

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I have a function that I'm using in a view where it is used in a loop. So it is used multiple times. I think because of this I have the N+1 issue. In my functions I'm eager loading the models but I still get the N+1 warning.

My Function on the TaskController

```
public function appDefaultPassword($newUserAccount, $newUserId)
{

    // Check if application default_password is set
    if($this->application->default_password) {
        return $this->application->decryptDefaultPass();
        // Check if application use_network_password is true
    } elseif($this->application->use_network_password) {
        // Get newUserAccount

        $newUser = $newUserAccount->with('applications')->where('id', $newUserId)->first();
        $netapp = $newUser->applications->where('app_type', 'LDAP')->first();
        $tasks = $this->with('actions')->where('model_id', $newUserAccount->id)->where('application_id', $netapp->id)->first();
        $taskAction = $tasks->actions->where('password', !NULL)->last();

        return decrypt($taskAction->password);
    }
}
```

In my NewUserAccountController I'm also eager loading applications and task.actions

```
public function show($newUserAccount)
{
    $newUserAccount = NewUserAccount::with('applications', 'task.application.admins', 'task.actions', 'approvalActions')->find($newUserAccount);
}
```

In my view:

```
@foreach($newUserAccount->task as $task)
...

    {{ $task->appDefaultPassword($newUserAccount->id) }}

...
@endforeach
```

I'm using Laravel N+1 Query Detector which detects this N+1 problem.
I'm not sure how to fix my function to satisfy this.

[image]

Using @Watercayman advise...
UPDATED CODE:

appDefaultPassword method

```
$netapp = $newUserAccount->applications->where('app_type', 'LDAP')->first();
$tasks = $newUserAccount->task->where('model_id', $newUserAccount->id)->where('application_id', $netapp->id)->first();
foreach($tasks->actions as $taskAction);
$taskAction = $tasks->actions->where('password', !NULL)->last();

return decrypt($taskAction->password);
```

View:

```
{{ $task->appDefaultPassword($newUserAccount) }}
```

Comment: appDefaultPassword should get as first parameter a UserAccount element, but you are passing only the id of this UserAccount

Comment: please also post the database structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view is *initially* getting a `$newUserAccount` with eager loaded `applications`.  So the `$newUserAccount` collection in that loop will have the `applications` loaded.

However, while looping on that blade page, you are passing the `id` of the `newUserAccount` back to the controller, where you are loading a brand new `newUserAccount` model *every time in that loop*.

Further, this line:

```
$newUser = $newUserAccount->with('applications')->where('id', $newUserId)->first();
```

is partly where your `n+1` issue is coming from.  Your `$newUserAccount` object has come in from route model binding (I assume, though you don't have the type hint -- but it would break unless that object is coming in), but you are eager loading the `applications` on a NEW instance within every loop from blade.

So it is sending the `id`, making the `newUserAccount` object, then loading the applications over and over.

There is another issue with that line: `$newUserAccount` is already a single object that has come in from the parameters of the method - it already IS the first object based on the `id`, but you are running the above line as if it was a collection.  I think this is probably extraneous, but I'm not sure as I don't really know where that object in the params is coming from.

To fix the repeat database calls, do all of your preparation logic in that `appDefaultPassword()` method *before* sending to your blade file, rather than having the blade file keep calling back to the controller in every loop of the `newUserAccount->tasks`.  In other words, before going to blade the first time, have the `newUserAccounts`, AND get a list of `$taskAction->passwords` ahead of time that you can pick from within the logic of the blade loop.